# JMeter Recording: 401 Unauthorized response after changed HTTP proxy to localhost

Tags: performance, jmeter

I just start learning JMeter. I'm trying to use JMeter to record my company websites, .NET web application.

**My issue is that**: **For security, to access the websites, we have to config "Manual proxy configuration" to 10.x.x.x:3128. However, to record in JMeter I have to change the config to localhost, port 3128.**

After I changed the config to localhost, I click Start button of HTTP Test Script Recorder then I click on any link, the Authorization dialog displays and I keep getting 401 unauthorized error although I enter correct username/password.

I tried to use HTTP Authorization Manager, HTTP Request Defaults or HTTP Request but they do not work.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your company uses proxy for Internet access you can "tell" JMeter to use this proxy as well. So you need to perform the following configuration:

1. Configure JMeter to use your proxy to access Internet via following command-line arguments (as per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)):

   > If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with the following parameters:
   >
   > -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
   >
   > -P [proxy server port]
   >
   > -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
   >
   > -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
   >
   > -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
   >
   > Example : jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
2. Add [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) with **default** port of 8080 (or any other)
3. Configure your browser to use **JMeter host** and port **8080** for accessing Internet. If there is `No proxy for localhost, 127.0.0.1` stanza somewhere in browser's proxy configuration - untick or remove it in case of running browser and JMeter on the same machine. "Classic" Firefox configuration should look something like:

[image: Firefox Recording Config]

4. It may be easier to use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), in that case you don't need to worry about proxy settings, SSL certificates and associated configuration, cookies, etc.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I cannot use Chrome extension because of the security, so I only can use Jmeter recorder. However, I tried to run JMeter from command line with the following command: "jmeter -H 10.9.x.x -P 3128 -N localhost" and my Firefox config is exactly the same as the attached image but it did not work; the authentication dialog was displayed again and again although I entered correct username/password. Is there anything else I need to config to log in successfully?